# Using a Project resource pool, must that pool file be open, to make changes in sharer plans?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

Using MS Project 2010 & new to resource pools and sharer plans. If I have a sharer plan open, and make changes to tasks/assigments -- is the resource pool file updated somehow, even if it's not open in Project at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Open the Resource pool first and close it last

When you open a sharer file that shares resources from a pool, you should have seen a dialog like this:
[image: Open resource pool]

In any case, if you didn't have the pool file open, that project would have used own resources when making assignments (nothing else is available). I am afraid you will have to fix this manually.

For future reference, you should open the Resource pool first and close it last.